# How to Fix Error CS0029 Can not implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Windows.Forms.Button

Tags: c#, winforms

I can not add the link in BUtton1

```
public partial class pForm : Form

    {
        public pForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Globals.pForm = this;

            INIFile inif = new INIFile(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "NewTeam");

            Globals.ServerURL   = Decrypt(inif.Read("Config", "Link"));

            Globals.BinaryName  = Decrypt(inif.Read("Config", "Main"));

            this.button1 = Decrypt(inif.Read("Config", "Site"));

        }
```

if someone is following help me thank you

Comment: Anyway, this appears to be C++ code.

Comment: @WeatherVane I don't think so, maybe C#?

Comment: Would you help me

Comment: `Decrypt` returns string value and you are trying to assign that to button type variable. That's not possible that's why you are getting this error. If your intention is to set the text of the button then you should do `this.button1.Text = Decrypt(....`

Comment: yes, I just wanted it when I clicked on the buton, I opened the stringg link

Comment: You don't *open strings*. What do you want to do with this string? Show it somewhere?

Comment: I am modifying a launcher of muonline int I configured the file for the person to return the link that it wants there in the form when clicking on the button open the link